# An incorrect(?) proof of the Hilbert's Basis Theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification, alternative-proof, noetherian, polynomial-rings

This is my proof of the Hilber's Basis Theorem.
I think it is incorrect. 
Because it is easier than other proofs.
But I can't find out the mistake in my proof.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

*Claim* If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $R[x]$ is also a Noetherian ring.

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $I[x]$ be an ideal in $R[x]$,
where $I$ is an ideal of $R$.
Since $R$ is Noetherian,
$I$ is finitely generated.
Suppose that $I=\langle b_1, b_2, ..., b_n\rangle=\{r_1 b_1+r_2 b_2+\cdots+r_n b_n\mid r_1, r_2, ..., r_n\in R\}$.
For any $f(x)\in I[x]$,
suppose that $f(x)=a_m x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots +a_1 x+a_0\in I[x]$
and
$$
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    a_m \\
    \vdots \\
    a_1 \\
    a_0 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccccc}
    r_{m,1} & r_{m,2} & \cdots & r_{m,n} \\
    r_{m-1,1} & r_{m-1,2} & \cdots &  r_{m-1,n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots \\
    r_{1,1} & r_{1,2} & \cdots &  r_{1,n} \\
    r_{0,1} & r_{0,2} & \cdots &  r_{0,n} \\
  \end{array}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    b_1 \\
    b_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    b_n \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
f(x)=
\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    x^m & \cdots & x & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    a_m \\
    \vdots \\
    a_1 \\
    a_0 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    x^m & \cdots & x & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccccc}
    r_{m,1} & r_{m,2} & \cdots & r_{m,n} \\
    r_{m-1,1} & r_{m-1,2} & \cdots &  r_{m-1,n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots \\
    r_{1,1} & r_{1,2} & \cdots &  r_{1,n} \\
    r_{0,1} & r_{0,2} & \cdots &  r_{0,n} \\
  \end{array}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    b_1 \\
    b_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    b_n \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$
Therefore,
$I[x]$ is also generated by $\{b_1, b_2, ..., b_n\}$
and $R[x]$ is Noetherian.

Comment: Is every ideal of $R[x]$ of the form $I[x]$ for some ideal $I\subset R$? And how does this argument go through for the ideal $(x)\subset \Bbb{Z}[X]$, for example?

Comment: Oh! Thanks. You point out the mistake of my proof. I don't remember why I have a impression that there is a theorem state: If $A$ is an ideal of $R[x]$, then $A=I[x]$ for some ideal $I$ in $R$. Please repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every ideal of $R[x]$ is of the form $I[x]$ for some ideal $I\subset R$, so your proof is lacking.

Moreover, your argument doesn't go through for the ideal $(X)\subset\Bbb{Z}[X]$, for example.